# How we can put Hyperlink footer text to many Pdf?

Tags: pdf, editing

How we can put Hyperlink footer text to many PDF.
Like if we want to add our website ( www.websitename.com ) name to many PDF of every page footer.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How are you creating the PDF?

Comment: Students supplies me thousands of pdf, there i have to put our website name at every page footer. I will be very thankful! if you help us.

Comment: How do they get the PDF to you?

Comment: collecting from internet and friends.

Comment: So you're looking for a solution you can trigger manually?

Comment: Automatically to every pdf

Comment: You'll need to elaborate then.